# Reading excel Tuples with condition in Python3

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to make a program that is able to read an excel file and then save in a variable which of the values of the list is bigger than certain value, but I keep getting the error:"'int' object is not iterable". However if I use an list that is inside my code works fine. Can anyone help?
Sorry for the bad english.
This is what I have so far:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'example.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Plan1')
for i in range(1, 7):
    age = []
    age = (sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).value)
numbers = [1, 5, 6, 8, 11, -1, -5, 7, -7 -11, -20]
#If i use numbers instead of age works just fine
velho = ([ num for num in age if num < 6 ])
print(velho)
```

Comment: What is the value of `sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).value` ?

Comment: Its a list of numbers in an excel files, 22, 26, 74, 87, 56...

Comment: Are you sure its a list ? The error message suggests its an int .

Comment: Its a list...  I changed to python 2 and changed a few lines, is almost good now. Soon I´ll post the solution, hopefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop is confusing. You are setting `age` to a differnt value every time. Are you meaning to append to the list? To do that, declare `age = []` outside the loop, then call `age.append(val)` inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you! It's working now, although I changed to python2.